# Python + BeautifulSoup: How to get ‘href’ attribute of ‘a’ element?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have the following:

```
  html =
  '''<div class=“file-one”>
    <a href=“/file-one/additional” class=“file-link">
      <h3 class=“file-name”>File One</h3>
    </a>
    <div class=“location”>
      Down
    </div>
  </div>'''
```

And would like to get just the text of `href` which is `/file-one/additional`. So I did:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

link_text = “”

for a in soup.find_all(‘a’, href=True, text=True):
    link_text = a[‘href’]

print “Link: “ + link_text
```

But it just prints a blank, nothing. Just `Link:`. So I tested it out on another site but with a different HTML, and it worked.

What could I be doing wrong? Or is there a possibility that the site intentionally programmed to not return the `href`?

Thank you in advance and will be sure to upvote/accept answer!

Comment: Does your HTML actually have curly-quotes in it?

Comment: For that matter, why does your *code* have curly-quotes in it? What are you coding in? You need to use a text editor.

Comment: If you remove the parameter `text=True`, your code works for me

Comment: If you need more info on quotes, check this article out: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20090225-00/?p=19033

Comment: @downshift What does `text=True` do? Thought it returns in text form

Comment: @LyManeug, the `text` parameter expects a `string` type; from the [docs](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) "you can search for strings instead of tags"; the `text` parameter is used in earlier versions and has been changed to `string`; but yeah, I think using a `boolean` with `text` instead of a `string` is what was the problem.

Comment: Or maybe you were thinking of the passing `boolean` to the `soup.find_all` function as in [for tag in soup.find_all(True):`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#true)

Answer (score 44):

The 'a' tag in your html does not have any text directly, but it contains a 'h3' tag that has text. This means that `text` is None, and `.find_all()` fails to select the tag. Generally do not use the `text` parameter if a tag contains any other html elements except text content.

You can resolve this issue if you use only the tag's name (and the `href` keyword argument) to select elements. Then add a condition in the loop to check if they contain text.

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
links_with_text = []
for a in soup.find_all('a', href=True): 
    if a.text: 
        links_with_text.append(a['href'])
```

Or you could use a list comprehension, if you prefer one-liners.

```
links_with_text = [a['href'] for a in soup.find_all('a', href=True) if a.text]
```

Or you could pass a [`lambda`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#a-function) to `.find_all()`.

```
tags = soup.find_all(lambda tag: tag.name == 'a' and tag.get('href') and tag.text)
```

---

If you want to collect all links whether they have text or not, just select all 'a' tags that have a 'href' attribute. Anchor tags usually have links but that's not a requirement, so I think it's best to use the `href` argument.

Using `.find_all()`.

```
links = [a['href'] for a in soup.find_all('a', href=True)]
```

Using `.select()` with CSS selectors.

```
links = [a['href'] for a in soup.select('a[href]')]
```

Comment: Thought to inform you about a question that I find trouble figuring out myself. I'll be very glad if you give [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59594692/unable-to-use-https-proxy-within-urllib-request) a go. Thanks.

Comment: And if i have to print each of these links, how to do? Because its a list right, not a str..

Comment: @LincesMarques Why don't you use a for loop? `for link in links: print(link)`

Answer (score 6):

You can also use attrs to get the href tag with regex search

```
soup.find('a', href = re.compile(r'[/]([a-z]|[A-Z])\w+')).attrs['href']
```

Comment: Do you know why calling directly `.href` does not work, but `.attrs['href']` works fine? I just spent 15 min to debug this :(

Answer (score 5):

1. First of all, use a different text editor that doesn't use curly quotes.
2. Second, remove the `text=True` flag from the `soup.find_all`

Answer (score 3):

You could solve this with just a couple lines of [gazpacho](https://github.com/maxhumber/gazpacho):

```py
from gazpacho import Soup

html = """\
<div class="file-one">
    <a href="/file-one/additional" class="file-link">
      <h3 class="file-name">File One</h3>
    </a>
    <div class="location">
      Down
    </div>
  </div>
"""

soup = Soup(html)
soup.find("a", {"class": "file-link"}).attrs['href']
```

Which would output:

```py
'/file-one/additional'
```

Answer (score 0):

if anyone still not getting href try this

```
  info=soup.find(‘a’, href=True):
  print (info.attrs.get("href"))
```

Answer (score -1):

A bit late to the party but I had the same issue recently scraping some recipes and got mine printing clean by doing this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

source = requests.get('url for website')
soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')

for article in soup.find_all('article'):
    link = article.find('a', href=True)['href'}
    print(link)
```

Comment: Please question yourself - How does this answer fundamentally differ from the previous and very extensive answers, what is the added value. In addition, please also check your approach for proper functioning. It is not about collecting badges, but about helping others with good answers.

Comment: not here for the badges or reputation, was just having the same problem and posted the solution that finally worked for me despite the various other posts.