# Cannot get the hyperlink href beautiful soup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I am trying to get the hyperlink of anchor (a) element but I get keep getting:

h ttps://in.finance.yahoo.com/h ttps://in.finance.yahoo.com/

[image]
I have tried all solutions provided here: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43814754/python-beautifulsoup-how-to-get-href-attribute-of-a-element/43814994)

Here's my code:

```
href_links = []
symbols = []
prices = []
commodities = []

CommoditiesUrl = "https://in.finance.yahoo.com/commodities"
r = requests.get(CommoditiesUrl)
data = r.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(data)

counter = 40
for i in range(40, 404, 14):
    for row in soup.find_all('tbody'):
        for srow in row.find_all('tr'):
            for symbol in srow.find_all('td', attrs={'class':'data-col0'}):
                symbols.append(symbol.text)
                href_link =  soup.find('a').get('href')
                href_links.append('https://in.finance.yahoo.com/' + href_link)
            for commodity in srow.find_all('td', attrs={'class':'data-col1'}):
                 commodities.append(commodity.text)
            for price in srow.find_all('td', attrs={'class':'data-col2'}):
                prices.append(price.text)


pd.DataFrame({"Links": href_links, "Symbol": symbols, "Commodity": commodities, "Prices": prices })
```

Also, I would like to know if it's feasible, to similarly to the website, to have the symbol of the commodity as a hyperlink in my pandas dataframe.

[image]

Comment: What on earth is the outer-most `for` loop for? `for i in range(40, 404, 14):` `i` isn't even referenced in the body of the loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what's going on with the code you posted, but you can simply get that URL by `find`ing an `a` element with the attribute `data-symbol` set to `GC=F`. The html has 2 such elements. The one you want is the first one, which is what is returned by `soup.find('a', {'data-symbol': 'GC=F'}).get('href')`.

```
import requests, urllib

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

CommoditiesUrl = "https://in.finance.yahoo.com/commodities"
r = requests.get(CommoditiesUrl)
data = r.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(data)

gold_href = soup.find('a', {'data-symbol': 'GC=F'}).get('href')

# If it is a relative URL, we need to transform it into an absolute URL (it always is, fwiw)
if not gold_href.startswith('http'):
    # If you insist, you can do 'https://in.finance.yahoo.com" + gold_href
    gold_href = urllib.parse.urljoin(CommoditiesUrl, gold_href)

print(gold_url)
```

> Also, I would like to know if it's feasible, to similarly to the website, to have the symbol of the commodity as a hyperlink in my pandas dataframe.

I'm not familiar with pandas, but I'd say the answer is yes. See: [How to create a table with clickable hyperlink in pandas & Jupyter Notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42263946/how-to-create-a-table-with-clickable-hyperlink-in-pandas-jupyter-notebook)